# jquery .load, simple question

Tags: jquery

```
function loadImage(currentImage)
{
    $('#loader').show();
    $('#photopreview').attr('src','img/' + currentImage).load(function() {  
        $('#loader').hide();
        $('#photopreview').show();
    });
}
```

---

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function() {
    loadImage(this.html);       
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseout", function() {
    $('#photopreview, #loader').hide();
});
```

When I hover my markers more than once, all i see is the loader, instead of loader -> image. Works well in Firefox, but not in IE and Chrome. Did i miss something? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

since the second time you hover your mouse over, IE and Chrome retrieves the image from browser cache, this is a very very fast process so that the image is load before you attach the load event handler, all you need to do is attach event handler before specify the src attribute:

```
$('#photopreview').load(function() /* your code */ }).attr('src', url);
```

if it still not work, please try this pattern, its more complicated but should work:

```
$('#loading').show();
var loaded = false;
function onimageload() {
    if (!loaded) {
        /* your code */
    }
}
var preview = $('#photopreview').load(onimageload).attr('src', url);
// since onload event may not be triggered, detect it by "complete" property
if (preview[0].complete) {
    onimageload();
}
```

otherwise, it may be some problem with the load of image, try to assure that `#photopreview` exists the second time `mouseover` is triggered, and assign an `abort` and `error` event handler on it to detect other problems

Comment: That's a little weired, sorry for not solve your problem, please see my edit

Comment: wow thanks, works like a charm. Can't see why ur first answer isnn't enough though.

Comment: One small thing: when i hover the next image i will still see the "old" one until the new one has loaded. Any idea how to fix?

Comment: how about hide the old one first? like `$('#loading').show(); $('#photopreview').hide().attr(...`